# How to read data from microphone input in GNU/Octave?

Tags: function, matlab, stream, octave, microphone

For sure it is possible, but the question is how? Official docs on http://gnu.org/software/octave keeps quiet about that.

Are there any additional libraries or functions that I can use to get access to line input (microphone input) using GNU/Octave on Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try using Octave's [`record`](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Audio-Processing.html#doc%2drecord) function?

```
x = record(T, Fs);
```

where `T` is the time duration to record, and `Fs` is the sampling rate.

Comment: when I try record I get this error:


octave:1> record(1)
Please hit ENTER and speak afterwards!
dd: opening `/dev/dsp': No such file or directory
error: fread: invalid stream number = -1
error: called from:
error:   /usr/share/octave/3.6.3/m/audio/record.m at line 53, column 13

I run that also as root, but this doesn't seem to work. But this is probably function that I'm looking for. Maybe this is a problem with operating system not with octave.

Comment: @crooveck Hmm, what is your OS? Try reading [this troubleshooting list](http://wiki.debian.org/SoundFAQ).

Comment: ok, I'm running ubuntu 12.04 64bits. 

The problem was with default record() implementation. Working solution is here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/octave3.2/+bug/681646 

Thanks for help @EitanT